# Query regarding SQL Normalization

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

I have various tables in a database. The tables basically emulate a step-by-step information insertion method by engineers through a website. They log all the data for a step and move on to the next step. There are 20 such steps which happen successively for a particular Module.

The tables are like (Cell Lot Table)

```
S.No.        Module Number       Lot Number     Signed By       Notes      Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             A1-001              DAX01          Lydia          No Error   9/17/2018 12:32:01 PM
2             A2-001              DAX01          Palmer         No Error   9/17/2018 12:34:11 PM
3             A1-001              DAX02          Patricia       No Error   9/17/2018 12:37:31 PM
```

(Curing Table)

```
S.No.        Module Number       Pre-Dispense Weight      Post-Dispense Weight      Signed By       Notes          Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             A1-001                3.2                      3.6                    Henry      Slightly higher       9/17/2018 12:39:01 PM
2             A2-001                3.1                      3.9                    Lydia      Very high             9/17/2018 12:45:01 PM
3             A2-001                2.1                      2.9                    Palmer     Within Range          9/17/2018 12:48:01 PM
```

Similarly, there are other tables, which take information in the same style as above.

The only issue is that the Module numbers can repeat in a table. Oftentimes, the engineers log the same step again in a table for a particular module, which leads to 2 data entries for it. As can be seen in Cell Lot Table for Module A1-001. They seem to want this feature as they like to trace-back on a module and see how it changed over time. This is the case across all tables.

What would be the best way to normalize this? Or should I use some other approach for creating my tables?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve?  What is the problem with the tables as they are now?

Comment: Just because you are repeating your `module number` doesn't mean it isn't properly normalized as-is. Looks good to me, OP.

Comment: As long as there are no redundant relationships between the module number and other columns (and it doesn't look like there are), this is fine.

Comment: If you don't like the idea of storing names like this repeatedly, you could create a `Modules` table, and replace `Module Number` with a foreign key to `Modules.id`.

Comment: Oh. I see. I felt my database designing was a little off as I couldn't see a primary key very evidently or a primary key foreign key connection across my tables, which is what people  keep in mind while working with rdbms systems.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & 

database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to 

record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.)